# How can I use WHERE with multiple different columns?

Tags: python, sql, string, sqlite, where-clause

Having trouble trying to query AND and OR in an SQlite3 statement.

Is there a way where I can do something like

`WHERE section = ? AND LEVEL =? AND subj1 =? AND subj2=? AND subj3 =?`

From what I see in this particular line

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE section = ? AND level =? AND subj1 = ? OR subj2 = ? OR subj3 =?
```

It won't work because after 'AND subj1 =?' SQlite3 now chooses to select whatever subject that subj2 and subj3 has, completely disregarding the section and level column.
How can I get the rows that have match the section, level and subjects that I want?

Here's my code

```
query = ("""SELECT * FROM students WHERE section = ? AND level =? AND subj1 = ? OR subj2 = ? OR subj3 =?"""
c.execute(query, (variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, variable5, ))
rows = c.fetchall()
print (rows)
```

Here's a sample table

```
Name        Section       Level        Subject 1       Subject 2      Subject 3
```

---

```
John    |      1      |     1      |      Math     |    Science    |    English
Mary    |      1      |     1      |      Math     |    Science    |    English
Dave    |      2      |     2      |      English  |    History    |    Math 
Joe     |      2      |     2      |      English  |    History    |    Math
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` has lower logical precedence than `AND`. To do what you want, you need to surround the `OR`ed predicates with parentheses:

```
SELECT * 
FROM students 
WHERE section = ? AND level = ? AND (subj1 = ? OR subj2 = ? OR subj3 =?)
```

However, here, it is simpler to use `IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM students 
WHERE section = ? AND level = ? AND ? IN (subj1, subj2, subj3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses:

```
WHERE section = ? AND level =? AND
      (subj1 = ? OR subj2 = ? OR subj3 = ?)
```

Assuming the last three parameters are the same, you can simplify this using `IN`:

```
WHERE section = ? AND level =? AND
      ? IN (subj1, subj2, subj3)
```

Usually `IN` has constants in the `IN` list and column names as the left operand.  However, that is not required.